# orderBy number angular js

Tags: angularjs, sql-order-by, angularjs-ng-repeat, parsefloat

I have an array of objects...

```
var userObjects =[
{userName: bob,
 age: "25",
 gender: "m"
},
{userName: bill,
 age: "15",
 gender: "m"
},
{userName: jen,
 age: "45",
 gender: "f"
},
]
```

Now I have an ng-repeat in my HTML to iterate over this array of objects.  I want it to sort the age:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in userObjects | orderBy:-age">
```

In my JS I am converting my ages to intergers....

```
data.forEach(function(user){
   user.age= parseFloat(user.age);
}
```

Angular will not sort by age, I would expect to see...

```
bill, 15
bob, 25
jen, 45
```

But instead they are all over the place. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try wrapping `-age` in single quotes, like `'-age'`

Answer (score 7):

Not necessary to convert strings to numbers in JS.

Make it in pure Angular with filter:

| orderBy:'-1*age'`

Answer (score 5):

Following will convert the 'age' into numeric and sort in ascending order.

`| orderBy : 'age/1'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this dude.....

ng-repeat="user in userObjects | orderBy:'age'">

Answer (score 0):

Ascending order:-

```
<div ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy:'age'">
```

Descending order:-

```
<div ng-repeat="person in persons | orderBy:'-age'">
```

Comment: The OP is already including that code in their question.  How does this help with anything?

Comment: @ryanyuyu He has the 'age' in quotes, which is correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',age:'18'},
        {name:'Carl',age:'32'},
        {name:'Margareth',age:'21'},
        {name:'Hege',age:'14'},
        {name:'Joe',age:'36'},
        {name:'Gustav',age:'42'},
        {name:'Birgit',age:'28'},
        {name:'Mary',age:'58'},
        {name:'Kai',age:'26'}
        ];
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<p>Looping with objects:</p>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:'age'">
    {{ x.name + '-' + x.age }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that this sort is a lexicographical sort, not a numerical sort, so if you had ` {name:'Bob',age:'100'}` in the list, they'd appear at the top, not the bottom, as it's comparing the string `'100'`, not the the number `100`. Something like `orderBy:'1*age'` would solve that.